# Simple static drop down example

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 5 EF with Scaffolding, and am trying to come up with a simple static drop down choice list.

I have a client, and would like a drop-down choice list of states.   For now, I would like the list to be hard-coded.

So far, I have figured out if I create a State model class with a "StateID" property, and add the same StateID to my Client class, scaffolding recognizes it as a foreign key.   However, there are no choices in the drop down.

```
public string stateID { get; set; }
```

I think my issue is how to populate the list of state objects somewhere for scaffolding.   All the examples online I can find are adding code to either the controller or view.   The problem there, is when I regenerate my scaffolding off my model, my view and controller code is going to regenerate.  This IS what I want, I just need to know how to populate the static data in the model, or similar?

I tried creating this class based on some research, but I think it's either not correct, or I need to somehow call the GetStates() in my Clinet model?

```
public class State
    {
        public string StateID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<State> GetStates()
        {
            return new List<State>
            {
                new State {
                    StateID = "MA",
                    Name = "Massachusetts"
                },
                new State{
                    StateID = "CT",
                    Name = "Conneticuit"
                },
                new State{
                    StateID = "RI",
                    Name = "Rhode Island"
                },
                new State{
                    StateID = "NH",
                    Name = "New Hampshire"
                }
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

This is the automatically generated scaffold view (which I am thinking I should not modify so that I am able to re-scaffold):

```
@model IEnumerable<MBDApp.Models.Client>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StateID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: I added it above.  Note that I am trying to keep this so I can continue to use scaffolding...

Comment: Can't see any DropDownListFor helper call in your view. I wonder how do you expect to get a dropdown without actually rendering a dropdown. Cut the crap with this scaffolding. If you want to get some real stuff you should totally forget about it and start writing code. You ain't gonna get what you want with a couple of clicks in Visual Studio and the scaffold stuff. If you want to develop in ASP.NET MVC you should be prepared to write code.

Comment: If that's the only answer, then fine.   Seems strange there would be so much put in to all this scaffolding and it has no support for a simple static drop down list.  Not even possible to override or extend the view class with CODE??

Comment: Hmm, I found a bug in my code and updated by question above - so now I am getting a DropDownList in my view!   Now, the issue is that there are no choices.  So the question is, how do I feed it a static list of choices as per above?

Comment: Never found an answer, but found the scaffolding so easy, I just created a model class for my 'State', scaffolded it and now the drop-down is data driven, also generated via mvc scaffolding.